# Why does it take more than the original alphabet to generate sets of strings?

Tags: computability, strings

I am reading Computability by Nigel Cutland and I'm stumped on a brief statement about generating particular sets of strings that is not explained or given any examples.

First, here are some *definitions* provided by Cutland. Let $\Sigma$ be a finite set of symbols, called an alphabet. Write $\Sigma^*$ to denote the set of all string from $\Sigma$. $\mathscr{G}$ is a Post-system over $\Sigma$ if it consists of a finite alphabet $\Sigma$, a finite subset of $\Sigma^*$ (the axioms), and a finite set of productions (ways of generating more strings from existing ones).

He then says **"Sometimes, in order to generate a particular set of strings in $\Sigma^*$ it is necessary to use *auxiliary symbols* in the generation process."**

I can imagine how certain string manipulations could only possibly be achieved with some placeholder symbols but for my life I cannot actually come up with an example.

More explicitly, I am struggling to find a situation for which a Post-system $\mathscr{G}$ over $\Sigma_1 \supseteq \Sigma$ is required to generate some particular $X \subseteq \Sigma^*$. Shouldn't some $\mathscr{G}$ over $\Sigma$ be sufficient?

Comment: I would read "necessary" as "convenient" and move on.

Comment: Try sigma = { a }, and X = all strings consisting of 3n or 4n a’s.

Comment: Are you referring to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_canonical_system)? What kind of rules do you allow?

Comment: Just for sake of it, would @gnasher729 like put it as an answer? Just so this question will be completed :3